# (Swift) How Do I Query for Snapshot of Only the Current User's Real-Time Data if my Nodes are Custom Indexed?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry if the title is a little wordy :P I'm using Swift and Firebase.

I've set a rule on Firebase to index my user database on "Username", but when I query in code for a snapshot of just the current user's data, it always returns nil... I'm guessing because I can only purely identify the current user by their uid??

This is my sample JSON tree:

[image]

As you can see above, in Firebase I've indexed my user's data based on their "Username" which they create within my app. 
But, when I want to retrieve the values of the other child nodes of the user, I can't even access the user's data tree because as far as the app is concerned when it's launched, it has no knowledge of the current user's "Username"... it only knows the uid of the current user indefinitely.

**What I want to do:**

I want to use `let user : String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!` and search my database for the child node value matching `user`, then I want to get a snapshot of that user's data... Starting at the header "**User1**" and include all it's children.

Please help me with the correct process to do this, I'm lost :P
Thanks!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear: *uid* is a unique identifier for every user in firebase. When the user logs in, get their uid from the Auth variable. From there you can access their users node via a node you've created */users/uid_x*. What else do you need beyond that? You don't even need a query - just access the node directly via *root_ref/users/uid_x*

Comment: @Jay Hmm, I wasn’t aware of that ‘root_ref’ option... I’m fairly new to Swift/Firebase and was under the impression (through research) that in order to retrieve data it had to be through a snapshot. In which case, diving multiple nodes deep wasn’t working because I would have to define the user’s specific node by their username (which is unknown at the time of application launch). But I’ll look into your suggestion further, thanks!

Comment: no no. I was using *root_ref* as a placeholder for a reference to *your* firebase i.e your_firebase_reference/users/uid_x. You do retrieve data in a snapshot and there are several ways to get one; observe, observeSingleEvent, and a query with an observe. Generally you define a users node to store additional user data;  root_ref/users/uid_0 and root_ref/users/uid_1 etc and then to access that user once they log in, *root_ref.child("users").child(some_uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value* will retrieve that specific user node.

Comment: Oh ok I follow now, thanks :) The only problem with that approach (for me) is that I'm indexing my Firebase data by the user's username, not by their uid. So when I get my snapshot and try to dive down into the user's data, I first define the "Users" node... good... but the next nodes in my database is every user's username (which I can't define at app launch). The user's uid is listed as a child inside that username node, so it's 'hidden' per say. I came up with a working alternative, but  I may have to eventually sort out a few problems with stability... answered above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The reason to use indexing is to speed up queries on certain nodes. If you don't query by the user name *frequently* then you woudn't need to index on it. i.e. if your users are stored in the pattern I mention, no queries are needed to get the users information after they authenticate as you will read it (observeSingle) by their uid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. I don't claim it to be the best approach, but it works and shows clearly how to retrieve a child value from it's key in Firebase as well:

All the code below is inside a regular custom function (not shown).

```
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil { //Makes sure that there is a user currently registered/logged in

    let ref = Database.database().reference() //Gets a reference to my database

    //Dives into the 'Users' node, then into the user's specific data node based on their username (gathered from device's 'User Defaults')
    ref.child("Users").child(username).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary //Gets a snapshot of all the data specific to the current user
        let usersEmail = value?.value(forKeyPath: "Email") //Gets the value of the specified key in the snapshot

        print(usersEmail!)

        })
    }
```

Prints "**a@b.com**". Since I'm indexing my Firebase database by each user's "Username" as the main node that contains the data children (rather then the user's **uid** as the main node), I need to save the user's username as a string in their device's user defaults so that I can recall that value when identifying the current user's data by their "Username"-specific node.

Note that this only works if your app supports testing for unique usernames when your user creates their username.

Comment: Hmmm. The code in this answer doesn't match the Firebase structure in your question and the question asks *How do you query* but this isn't a query. The code here shows how to observeSingle a Firebase node which is also shown in the [Firebase Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write?authuser=0) in the Read Data Once section. In your Firebase structure the username is a *child node* of the User1 node. Just asking for clarification for future readers.

Comment: Yes sorry, that would definitely be confusing. The 'username' that you pointed out... ref.child("Users").child(username)... is actually a variable that holds the retrieved value of the user's username from the User Defaults. It has a small 'u' as opposed to the Firebase child node "Username" with a large 'U'. The function that gets that value isn't included in the above code but I can add that tonight for clarity. Also, the original question asks how to query for a snapshot of the user's data if I can't define the node it's all hidden inside, but User Defaults is the answer in this case.

Comment: It's not hidden - you can always query for child nodes regardless of their key. In this case you could easily query the */Users* node for any child nodes that that contain a users *Email*, *User ID* or *Username*.

Comment: When trying to get all of the current user's data (only the current user, not other users' data as well), I think the problem I've run into is that when trying to dive into my real-time database, I have to get a snapshot from a structure like this: "/ A / B / C / abcd...", where each large letter is a sub-node, and the small letters are children. If I want to get a snapshot of only "abcd", I would need to define "C" as a path, but in the case of it being a username, that isn't known at app launch, so I retrieve it from where it had been saved in User Defaults. I'm open to other suggestions :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that's not how it works. You only need the path 'C' if you are directly accessing the children. i.e. given a path /users/uid_0/user_name: "c.sagen" and wanted to get uid_0 username it would be accessed by observing that path of /users/uid_0/user_name: and reading the snapshot.value. However, if you performed a *query* on the /users/ node, you would query for user_name = 'c.sagen' which would return the entire uid_0 node (or any other node with that user name). This is another good reason to use uid as the key to users nodes as it is always obtained from auth.uid.